# How to give this picker view a datasource

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uipickerview, subview

Here I am adding a pickerview programaticly

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,280,321,200);

        UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init]; //Not sure if this is the proper allocation/initialization procedure

        //Set up the picker view as you need it

        //Set up the display frame
        myPickerView.frame = pickerFrame; //I recommend using IB just to get the proper width/height dimensions

        //Add the picker to the view
        [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
    }
```

But now I need to actually have it display content and somehow find out when it changes and what value it has changed to. How do I do this?

Comment: have a look in the xcode docs for UIPickerView datasource and delegates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in .h file place this code

```
@interface RootVC : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

assign the datasource and delegate to the picker

```
// this view controller is the data source and delegate
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
```

use the following delegate and datasouce methods

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 200;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 50;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *returnStr = @"";
    if (pickerView == myPickerView)
    {       
        returnStr = [[levelPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
    }

    return returnStr;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == myPickerView)
    {
        return [levelPickerViewArray count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that implements the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol and assign an instance of it to `myPickerView.dataSource`.

Comment: How do I assign the instance?

Comment: @Michael You just set myPickerView.dataSource = (instance of your datasource). Where the datasource instance comes from is specific to your app. Just remember that UIPickerView doesn't retain its dataSource, so you will need to create/retain it in your view controller (if not elsewhere).