# How to customize hours in UIDatePicker in ios

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

i have a `UIDatePicker` in which i want to customize hours i want to display hours excluding 4 am-10 am .Is it possible using `UIDatePicker` in iOS.i tried but unable to get it,

```
 datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    datePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    datePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];
    datePicker.minuteInterval=35; NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
    NSDateComponents* addOneMonthComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
    addOneMonthComponents.day =6;
    NSDate* oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:addOneMonthComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0] ;
    datePicker.maximumDate = oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds ;
```

Comment: No, you can't limit the time. You will have to create custom picker for this.

Comment: i have done above for maintaing 35 min intervel and to show near by 7 days

Comment: There is a magical button called **edit** below the question, and leave [tag:xcode] alone; it's just an IDE tag

Comment: @Raptor is there any way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Set `NSDatePicker` formatter like this

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Hope this works for you .

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 pickers for this.

You can keep your `UIDatePicker` but the date picker mode is "Date Only".

For the time picker, you can implement a custom `UIDatePicker` which `UIPickerDataSource` is customized by you, filtering out 4am - 10am.

To give a `UIPicker` a custom data source, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382960/how-to-give-this-picker-view-a-datasource).